# Ionic 2, markers only appear once

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am starting a new Ionic 2 project and I am working with google maps markers.

This is the code at andalucia-mapa.ts:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams,  Platform  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleMaps } from '../../providers/google-maps';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import { Locations } from '../../providers/locations';
declare var google;
/*
  Generated class for the AndaluciaMapa page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-andalucia-mapa',
  templateUrl: 'andalucia-mapa.html'
})
export class AndaluciaMapaPage {

   @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('pleaseConnect') pleaseConnect: ElementRef;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public maps: GoogleMaps, public platform: Platform, public locations: Locations) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

        let mapLoaded = this.maps.init(this.mapElement.nativeElement, this.pleaseConnect.nativeElement);

         let locationsLoaded = this.locations.load();

            Promise.all([
                mapLoaded,
                locationsLoaded
            ]).then((result) => {

                let locations = result[1];

                for(let location of locations){
                    this.maps.addMarker(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                }

            });

        });

    }


}
```

The first time the page is executed, the markers are shown on the map.
But if I go back to another page and return to this page, the markers are not loading.

EDIT

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams,  Platform  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleMaps } from '../../providers/google-maps';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import { Locations } from '../../providers/locations';
declare var google;
/*
  Generated class for the AndaluciaMapa page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-andalucia-mapa',
  templateUrl: 'andalucia-mapa.html'
})
export class AndaluciaMapaPage {

   @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('pleaseConnect') pleaseConnect: ElementRef;
 locations:any;//declare locations

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public maps: GoogleMaps, public platform: Platform, public locations: Locations) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

        let mapLoaded = this.maps.init(this.mapElement.nativeElement, this.pleaseConnect.nativeElement);

         let locationsLoaded = this.locations.load();
 console.log("location",locationsLoaded);
            Promise.all([
                mapLoaded,
                locationsLoaded
            ]).then((result) => {

               this.locations = result[1];

                for(let location of this.locations){
                    this.maps.addMarker(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                }

            });

        });

    }


}
```

Comment: Could you please add a `console.log` just below the `this.platform.ready()...` and check if that console log is executed every time you enter the page? That way we can be sure that the life cycle event is ok, and the issue may be somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @sebaferreras, I have put it and it is executed every time I enter the page.

Comment: @sebaferreras; I have put two console.log, one below Promise.all and one inside the for loop. The first time all appear in the console, then only the first appears.

Comment: Great. Could you please add a debugger outside the for loop and check the content of the `this.locations` property? I think that since the map is already loaded, maybe the second time you should use `result[0]` instead of `result[1]` to get the list of locations but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 0):

put your code in

```
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    //put your code here
    }
    ionViewDidLoad(){
}
```

Runs when the page has loaded. This event only happens once per page being created.

Answer (score 0):

You have set location array as local to the then function.
[ionViewDidLoad](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/)  is called only the first time the page is created.
Set your location array as class variable and it should work.

```
export class AndaluciaMapaPage {

   @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('pleaseConnect') pleaseConnect: ElementRef;

locationCorodinates:any;//declare locations

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public maps: GoogleMaps, public platform: Platform, public locations: Locations) {

  }
```

....

In promise.all,

```
 Promise.all([
                mapLoaded,
                locationsLoaded
            ]).then((result) => {

                this.locationCorodinates= result[1];//remove declaration

                for(let location of this.locationCorodinates){
                    this.maps.addMarker(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                }
```

and in ionViewWillEnter

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
for(let location of this.locationCorodinates){
                        this.maps.addMarker(location.latitude, location.longitude);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there is a warning at locations here; for(let location of locations) . The warning message says: Cannot find name locations.

Comment: `locations:any[];//declare locations`

Comment: try now..and let me know

Comment: There was a line that you have removed: let locationsLoaded = this.locations.load();

Comment: There was a line that you have removed: let locationsLoaded = this.locations.load(); If removed, then line below mapLoaded throws erro

Comment: no I just showed the change to be made inside promise.all.. where you had done let locations..

Comment: I just havent put your entire class in the answer

Comment: If I put this.locations = result[1], and for(let location of this.locations), then there is only one warning at:     let locationsLoaded = this.locations.load(); it says property load doesn´t exist on type any[], and there is also a warning at  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public maps: GoogleMaps, public platform: Platform, public locations: Locations) {
 
  } at place public locations:Locations

Comment: what data type does `this.locations.load()` return? set the same in locations datatype instead of any[].

Comment: sorry, it is an error, this is the data returned: t {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array[0]}

Comment: after executing the app, when the map page loads it throws: EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined

Comment: locations where previously define in the constructor.

Comment: ohh..i get it you already have public locations: Locations in constructor!! is let locations = result[1]; same locations??

Comment: I have edited my question with the current code, Now the editor shows only an error at the constructor for public locations: Locations. Duplicate identifier locations

Comment: let me check, and thank you for your time and effort

Comment: No errors now, but the same behaviour, the first time the marker is shown, then if back to the page, the marker is not shown

Comment: try the for loop in ionviewdidenter or ionviewwilenter

Comment: both with the same result.

Comment: @user3713806  did you managed to solve this? If yes, can you post how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ionViewDidLoad` try to use `ionViewWillEnter`. It will definitely solve your issue.